# In a triangle $ABC$ with $BC=a,AB=c,AC=b$; the bisector of $ACB$ perpendicular with the line $OG$

Tags: geometry

Let triangle $ABC, BC=a,AB=c,AC=b$. Know that the bisector of $ACB$ perpendicular with the line $OG$, with $O$ is inscribed circle center and $G$ is center of $ABC$. Prove that:
$$\frac{2ab}{a+b}=\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "$G$ being the center of (triangle) $ABC$"?

Comment: Let M,N,P is Midpoint of BC,AC,AB. G is intersection of AM,BN and CP. Sorry because of my bad English

Comment: G is the centroid(http://www.jimloy.com/geometry/centers.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the home work is finished and this answer is for reference.

[image: the answer]